# Grails could not read entry ':compileGroovy' from cache taskArtifacts.bin

Tags: windows, grails, groovy

I've been running a project on grails 3.2.6 on Windows 10 for quite a while now but while I was trying to fix some errors on a service and controller I suddenly get this error and can't run my grails app. Sorry it's so long. I don't know what to do. :(

> This is what I got before stacktrace.

```
Could not read entry ':compileGroovy' from cache taskArtifacts.bin (C:\Users\kenic\Desktop\tccs-rest\.gradle\3.0\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin).
java.io.EOFException (no error message)
```

> This is from the stacktrace.

```
 Error Failed to start server (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-bin.zip'.
        at java_util_concurrent_Future$get.call(Unknown Source)
        at run-app.run(run-app.groovy:89)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.script.GroovyScriptCommand.handle(GroovyScriptCommand.groovy:152)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.handleCommand(AbstractProfile.groovy:481)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:377)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:350)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:271)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-bin.zip'.
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:77)
        at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil$_runBuildWithConsoleOutput_closure3.doCall(GradleUtil.groovy:88)
        at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil$_withProjectConnection_closure1.doCall(GradleUtil.groovy:69)
        at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil$_withProjectConnection_closure1.call(GradleUtil.groovy)
        at grails.io.support.SystemOutErrCapturer.withNullOutput(SystemOutErrCapturer.groovy:64)
        at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil.withProjectConnection(GradleUtil.groovy:68)
        at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil.runBuildWithConsoleOutput(GradleUtil.groovy:83)
        at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleInvoker.invokeMethod(GradleInvoker.groovy:50)
        at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleAsyncInvoker$_invokeMethod_closure2.doCall(GradleAsyncInvoker.groovy:57)
        at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleAsyncInvoker$_invokeMethod_closure2.doCall(GradleAsyncInvoker.groovy)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Could not read entry ':compileGroovy' from cache taskArtifacts.bin (C:\Users\kenic\Desktop\tccs-rest\.gradle\3.0\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin).
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
        at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:100)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:59)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:240)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not read entry ':compileGroovy' from cache taskArtifacts.bin (C:\Users\kenic\Desktop\tccs-rest\.gradle\3.0\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin).
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.get(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:128)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache$1.create(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:37)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.readFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:159)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$UnitOfWorkFileAccess.readFile(DefaultCacheAccess.java:396)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.get(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.InMemoryTaskArtifactCache$1.get(InMemoryTaskArtifactCache.java:98)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$2.create(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:125)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$2.create(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:120)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:102)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:183)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.loadHistory(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.getHistory(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.getStateFor(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.ShortCircuitTaskArtifactStateRepository.getStateFor(ShortCircuitTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:48)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:55)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.kryo.KryoBackedDecoder.maybeEndOfStream(KryoBackedDecoder.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.kryo.KryoBackedDecoder.readNullableString(KryoBackedDecoder.java:142)
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.kryo.KryoBackedDecoder.readString(KryoBackedDecoder.java:135)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$LazyTaskExecution$TaskHistorySerializer.readSnapshotIds(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:369)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$LazyTaskExecution$TaskHistorySerializer.read(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:307)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$TaskHistorySerializer.read(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:182)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$TaskHistorySerializer.read(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:168)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache$DataBlock.getValue(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:661)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.get(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:120)
        ... 83 more
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer underflow.
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.require(Input.java:162)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readUtf8_slow(Input.java:495)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readUtf8(Input.java:488)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readString(Input.java:418)
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.kryo.KryoBackedDecoder.readNullableString(KryoBackedDecoder.java:140)
        ... 90 more
| Error Failed to start server
```

Comment: Try resetting your taskArtifacts cache (rename to `taskArtifacts.bin.old`) Also a gradlew clean may help.

Comment: Hey @JacobPersi I got it to work! I renamed taskArtifacts.bin and did a grails gradle command on cmd and it showed something else along with the compilegroovy error. It showed a strange invisible box somewhere in my code. I notice I've been getting a few of these lately but only now did cmd reveal it after going back and forth. While I'm not sure if what you recommended fixed things I'm still really grateful. Thanks so much! Cheers! :D